Redirect http domain to another https domain without warning?
My main domain is mydomain.org, with a SSL certificate (https).  And I have other domains (.com, .net, sub domains of the .org) that point to the main one (.org) (redirect), but they don't have SSL certificates.
I currently have a standard ssl for the main domain only.  But now when users open any of the other domains (http), or subdomains of the .org, they get and warning in the browser that it "doesn’t support a secure connection", and stops there, and doesn't forward to the .org domain. as it used to.
Is there a .htaccess lines to add to fix that? Or any other way?  Or the only way is buy a Multi-Domain Wildcard SSL certificate?

The browser correctly tells the users that they're attempting to open an insecure connection.
The only possible (and the correct) fix is to encrypt that connection.
There's no reason you'd need a costly or complicated TLS certificate for that; a simple self-requested letsencrypt certificate will definitely do. certbot makes getting one (and keeping it renewed automatically) a 5 minute operation.

Arguably the "best"  solution is to obtain one TLS certificate that includes all your domain names as "extra" domains (which can be embedded in the certificate with the Certificate Subject Alternative Name (SAN) TLS extension) as that has the best support for legacy clients that don't support SNI. When supporting legacy clients is not a requirement there is no objection to getting additional TLS certificates for your additional domains instead.
The first allows you to configure the Apache TLS VirtualHost with a ServerAlias that includes all your domains and subdomains like for example:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  example.org
    ServerAlias www.example.org example.net www.example.net
    SSLCertificateFile /.../one-cert-that-contains-all-domains.pem
    ...
</VirtualHost>

When you don't want the use the ServerAlias feature to make the same site available with all your domain names, you would create a set-up like this, where you have an additional VirtualHost block that redirects all your other domains to your main example.org website with the inexpensive Redirect directive:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  example.org
    SSLCertificateFile /.../one-cert-that-contains-all-domains.pem
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  www.example.org
    ServerAlias example.net www.example.net
    SSLCertificateFile /.../one-cert-that-contains-all-domains.pem
    Redirect / https://example.org/ 
    ...
</VirtualHost>

When you need to use unique certificates for each domain: simple create as many additional VirtualHost blocks  as you need, each with a specific domain in the ServerName and a matching SSLCertificateFile.

When a new/additional certificate is not an option, you can at least ensure that site vistors that access your secondary domain names over plain, clear text HTTP get redirected directly to correct HTTPS site, to example.org for which you do have valid certificate. That won't prevent errors for the users that attempt to access those secondary sites directly over HTTPS, but might already be a small improvement.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  example.org
    ServerAlias www.example.org example.net www.example.net
    Redirect / https://example.org/
</VirtualHost>

If you're on shared hosting and can't modify the apache VirtualHost blocks and absolutely need to rely on mod_rewrite and a .htaccess file you can make a similar improvement to step away from the common parameterised  redirect to https:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

and redirect explicitly to the example.org which does have a valid certificate with:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

